# Passing a UIImage to a SubView's UIImageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to pass a UIImage value to a UIImageView inside a View that I'm adding as a subView.

Here's what I'm doing in my mainViewController:

```
- (IBAction)selectStore:(id)sender {

    StoreSelectorViewController *SSVC = [[StoreSelectorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StoreSelectorViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController addChildViewController:SSVC];
    [SSVC.backgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CoolBG.png"]];
    [self.view.window addSubview:SSVC.view];
}
```

I did the following in my StoreSelectorViewController.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundView;
```

And I also linked it in the XIB file.

Everything loads, except that I never receive the UIImage value. Thanks

Comment: Is `selectStore:` getting called? You have it set as an `IBAction`, but are you sure you wired it in correctly in Interface Builder? Perhaps put a `NSLog` statement in that message to ensure it's called.

Comment: Hey Greg! Yeah In fact I actually have a Button in StoreSelectorViewController, which does appear on the screen, and then when I click it, it removes the whole view. So it seems like the problem has to do specifically with the uiimageview. Let me try a few NSLogs.

Comment: Also, this looks a bit odd. You're adding a subview to the `UIWindow`, not the current `UIView`, but you're also adding another `UIViewController` to the `UINavigationController`. Are you sure you don't mean to `[self.navigationController pushViewController]`, and not add the subview or CVC?

Comment: I'm trying to add the subView in front of the navigationController that MainViewController is in, that's why I'm trying to add it to the UIWindow, rather than the ViewController's view.

Comment: I have updated the ans please follow and make it correct. If it really helps

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using this doesn't seem to work:

```
[SSVC.backgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CoolBG.png"]];
```

So instead I use this two line version, in a slightly dif't order, setting the image, before displaying its parent (SSVC):

```
StoreSelectorViewController *SSVC = [[StoreSelectorViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"StoreSelectorViewController" bundle:nil];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CoolBG.png"];
[SSVC.backgroundView setImage:img];
[self.navigationController addChildViewController:SSVC];
[self.view.window addSubview:SSVC.view];
```

Comment: See comment/edit above, lets try creating these in a dif't order.

Comment: @Fluffhead, addSubview is the method of only UIView. I mean inspite of that self.view.window addSubview. It should be like this self.view addSubview right??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line     `[self.view.window addSubview:SSVC.view];`  So just replace the line to below:-

Also you want to add `imageview` as a `subview` of `view`. So use below code where `backgroundView` is the `imageview`:-

```
[SSVC.view addSubview:SSVC.backgroundView];
[self.view addSubview:SSVC.view];.
```

Comment: It actually breaks it now. Thanks though!

Comment: I mean after adding this line of code. you have to add like this [self.view addSubview:SSVC.view];. Did you try??

Comment: Did you remember to synthesize backgroundView in the .m?

Comment: If the xcode version is higher then it will autosynthesize. No need to do manually.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be calling `addChildViewController` regardless, it's not what you want. You're not making use of the `UIViewController` either, just stealing its `view` property. It's possible that because of this, the `UIViewController` is not fully instantiated since it's not presented (`viewWill/Did`) methods never get called, and so `backgroundView` is probably `nil`.

Comment: What would you recommend? I'm trying to create a custom view using an xib. Thanks!

Comment: @user1886754, also did you try to add backgroundView on your view??

Comment: There's also nothing wrong with just making a UIViewController that doesn't fill the screen.